# Is the category of sets and functions Kleisli?

Tags: category-theory, monads

I think that the category of sets and functions, or perhaps just the category of finite sets and functions, is a Kleisli category for some, probably trivial, monad.  Is this so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every category $C$ is the Kleisli category on the identity monad on $C$.